# How can I use curl command in multi-line way?

Tags: curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to use a curl command which I've found out somewhere in stack overflow community. I have edited it according to my needs (adding my creds and all) the same command if I try to use as a multi-line command fails. I am confused where I have mistaken.

The working command:

```
 curl -X PUT --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' -F content=@README.md -F 'message=Updated using file-edit REST API' -F branch=master -F sourceCommitId='' http://bitbucket.org/rest/api/latest/projects/MYP/repos/test/browse/README.md
```

The failing command:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://bitbucket.org/api/latest/projects/myp/repos/my-repo/browse/README.md' \
 --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' \
 -F 'content=@README.md'
 -F 'message=Updated using file-edit REST API' \
 -F 'branch=master'
```

for the failing command the response is 404 not found.

Comment: So why not use the one that works?  I think it's an OS issue.  Some allow, many do not.

Comment: I just want to understand the difference. Anyway, I'm not gonna use it simply like this I'll have to automate this so I'm gonna use ansible or python.

Comment: Looks like the second line (with the README) is missing the backslash (\\). Also one of them uses `MYP/repos/test` and another uses `myp/repos/my-repo` - don't know if that matters or if bitbucket is case-sensitive.

Comment: Or it could be the missing backslash on the third line.